# nvarchar(200) but exception says string must have length of 20

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am using sql Database.In one table I have column named ClientName(nvarchar(200),null).I have give it nvarchar(200) though I get exception:
**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details**.

In EntityValidationErrors I am getting

**The field ClientName must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '20'.**

What is the solution ?

Comment: Your model has an attribute that doesn't match the column.

Comment: I have not given any attribute to ClientName except Required @CodeCaster

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve].